# filebaseのサンプルがあったので試しているのですが、Swift4の為エラーが表示されます。

Tags: swift4

Firebase のサンプルがあったので試しているのですが、 Swift 4 の為エラーが表示されます。

https://github.com/fumiyasac/FirebaseSimpleTodo

```
//データの取得を行う
Todolist.observeSingle(.value, block: { todos in
```

このステップのところで

> Ambiguous reference to member 'observeSingle(_:block:)'

になってしまいます。

Swift 4 での記入の仕方を教えて戴けないでしょうか。

Comment: Xcode9のSwift3モードでもコンパイルできませんし、単純なSwift4での構文変更によるものではありません。特定のバージョンのSwift3コンパイラでは(Swiftのバグにより)コンパイルできたのかもしれませんが、「たとえSwift3でもコンパイルできるのがおかしい」と言うコードになっています。かなりしっかり作られたサンプルのようですので、どなたか(開発者ご本人を含めて)が最新のSwiftでコンパイルできるように作り変えるのを待たれるか、あきらめて他のサンプルコードを探された方が良いように思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました。他を探して見ます。